# How to identify an iisreset in an asp.net web application?

Tags: asp.net, iis

I've got an application that needs to do some work on startup (before the first request is in).
I've added the initialization code in the global.asax file (Application_start method) but this code doesn't seem to be hit after an iis reset is performed.
Is there an event which is triggered in an asp.net application when an iis reset has occurred?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/09/15/auto-start-asp-net-applications-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx

This may be of help to you.

Tho the features are new to IIS 7.5 which is only on Windows Server 2008 R2 / Windows 7.

> #### Auto-Start Web Applications with ASP.NET 4
>
> Some web applications need to load large amounts of data, or perform expensive initialization processing, before they are ready to process requests.  Developers using ASP.NET today often do this work using the “Application_Start” event handler within the Global.asax file of an application (which fires the first time a request executes).  They then either devise custom scripts to send fake requests to the application to periodically “wake it up” and execute this code before a customer hits it, or simply cause the unfortunate first customer that accesses the application to wait while this logic finishes before processing the request (which can lead to a long delay for them).
>
> ASP.NET 4 ships with a new feature called “auto-start” that better addresses this scenario, and is available when ASP.NET 4 runs on IIS 7.5 (which ships with Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2).  The auto-start feature provides a controlled approach for starting up an application worker process, initializing an ASP.NET application, and then accepting HTTP requests.

**Edit:** Link to more information about Auto Start feature.

http://www.asp.net/LEARN/whitepapers/aspnet4#0.2__Toc253429241

Comment: Unfortunately, we're still using .net 3.5. This might be the trigger to upgrade...

Comment: It's what made me upgrade! I can't find the whitepaper for IIS7.5 but theres a bunch of other nifty features with .Net 4.0 and IIS7.5.

Answer (score 4):

Application start happens on first request, not on iisreset.

The site doesn't start itself..

See "Restart cache item callback on web process restart" [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ASPNETService.aspx).

> In such cases, the service will stop
>   running unless a page is hit and the
>   Application_Start is called.
>   Application_Start is called only when
>   a page is visited for the first time
>   in a web project.

I would suggest having a batch file that contains iisreset and an "iexplore mypage" call

Edit: apparently, you can use [application end to trigger application start.](http://forums.asp.net/p/1570224/3938950.aspx) YMMV